# Sort arrayList in ascending and descending order

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

The following method receives two array list of integers objects and a Boolean indicating the sorting order (ascending, if true; descending, if false), and returns an array list with all the elements from both arrays sorted. I know how to sort individual array list using Arrays.sort(array), but I am getting lost on how to combine the two array list.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> getSorted(ArrayList<Integer> FIRST,
           ArrayList<Integer> SECOND, boolean ascendingly){
```

Comment: Why don't you `addAll` from one list to the other?

Comment: Are the arrays already sorted?

Comment: no, they are not sorted

Answer (score 2):

A hint to solve your problem .

1. you can combine two arraylist into one either by adding them to a temp one, or adding two in either one.
2. now call `Arrays.sort`  method to sort the list.

Answer (score 2):

for an array you can always use Arrays.sort()

And,if you want collections to be sorted you can use

```
Collections.sort(listName);
```

for ascending order,and

```
Collections.sort(listName, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

for descending order

Just a hint

Hope this helps!
Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Collections may be good for this case.
such as :

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList=new ArrayList<Integer>()
if(first not null && first.size() > 0){
   newList.addAll(first)
}
//so does second list
...
newList.AddAll(second)

if(newList.size>1){
  if(order){
    Collections.sort(newList)
  }else{
    Collections.reverse(newList)
  }
}
return newList
```